# Do Pokémon trainers develop some kind of limited resistance to their Pokémon's abilities?

Tags: pokemon

Obvious comedic aspects of the cartoon show especially aside, this may be a partial explanation. Think about it:

James can breathe Weezing's smog with no ill effects.
Brock was able to hug a Sharpedo. And Ash has gotten trampled, tossed, smacked, singed, smothered, submerged, routed, run over, and **electrocuted** so often by his Pokemon he should be *perpetually hospitalized!* Yet these characters **always** seem to bounce back without serious injury.

Considering [a] it *is* partially cartoon logic, and [b] Pokémon trainers, much like animal handlers, likely *will* get somewhat more sturdy and hardy from simply regularly dealing with the animals they train....

Is it *at all* possible that just *being* around a Pokémon somehow helps their trainers develop a higher resistance to that Pokémon's special abilities?

Answer (score -3):

No Pokémon powers are naturally harmless to humans, trainers do not need special resistance.

As you pointed out, many trainers have been exposed to Pokémon attacks and suffered no injuries. But also note that many opponents have also been hit by Pokémon attacks and suffered no injuries. Examples:

- Garchomp uses his hyper beam hitting Meowth and Team Rocket, destroying concrete and steel. But Jesse and James are not harmed.
- Season 1, e63 Jessie & James were in charge of the gym and they set a trap where trainers would feel the pain of Pokémon attacks. Machomp uses a brutal Karaté Chop on Ash’s Squirtle and Ash is seriously shaken, but is only mildly impaired.

Several other canonical examples of humans enduring Pokémon attacks [can be seen in this video](https://youtu.be/Y_50wAHtiHM).

[image]

I believe within Pokémon canon Pokémon powers are simply ineffective against humans, so trainers need no special resistance.

Comment: Why does Picachu and various other of Ash' Pokémon manage to use their powers to blast team rocket off again so successfully?

Comment: That’s a good question to ask! You want to know why or how they do it so often?

Comment: What's your citation that humans are immune to Pokémon attack?

Comment: I disagree. Humans aren't immune to Pokémon attacks, as shown multiple times in the videogames, where people warns you about the dangers of wandering alone without a Pokémon helping you.

Wild Pokémon are dangerous to human beings.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Pokémon, but didn't Ash die from Pokémon attacks in one of the movies?