# Are humans officially immune to Pokemon attacks?

Tags: pokemon

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221781/89771) claims that humans are immune to Pokemon attacks.

> I believe within Pokémon canon Pokémon powers are simply ineffective against humans, so trainers need no special resistance.

Yet I'm pretty sure that in the TV show, the games, and (especially) Detective Pokemon, humans have born the brunt of Pokemon attacks.

According to canon, are humans officially immune to Pokemon attacks? There may well be exceptions (say, a super-powerful Pokemon, or some other way), but has canon ever explicitly addressed this issue?

What I'm not looking for: Examples of humans being attacked by Pokemon and either taking damage or surviving. There are examples either way, but generally humans are not attacked or damaged by Pokemon, and an exception does not explain the general rule.

What I am looking for: a quote from the games, tv show, or any other canon explicitly addressing if or whether humans are immune to Pokemon attacks, or some other quote addressing why Pokemon do or do not attack humans.

Comment: Doesn't Team Rocket always fly into the sky because of Pokémon attack?

Comment: How in the world is this a dupe??? I freaking linked to the original question! The answer there merely provides examples. I want an official quote.

Comment: @TheAshsaysReinstateMonica Bounties are what you use when you want a more official answer not re-asking the question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'm clearly asking a different question. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/not-a-dupe-closed-as-dupe. Read them.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The original question asked if Pokemon breeding provides resistance. My question asks if all humans are immune to Pokemon. They are in no way similar questions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I am asking if Vogon Poet's claim - used to answer a different question - is true. I am not asking for another answer to that question, and would not provide a bounty for that question. For mine, I gladly would.

Comment: For the record, putting a link in your question to another semi-identical question isn't a magical barrier to getting your question not marked as a dupe. It just shows that you noticed the dupe yourself.

Comment: @Valorum Or that I'm asking a distinct question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Humans certainly are not immune to Pokémon attacks; quite the contrary. Nearly every game cites the dangers of running into wild Pokémon as why the player character should not venture into the long grass without their own Pokémon to protect them:

> OAK: Hey! Wait! Don't go out! It's unsafe! Wild POKéMON live in tall grass! You need your own POKéMON for your protection.

(Pokémon Red)

> Wait, GOLD! What do you think you're doing? It's dangerous to go out
>               without a POKEMON! Wild POKEMON jump out of the grass on the way to
>               the next town.

(Pokémon Gold)

We also see the direct result of Pokémon attacking humans in some games. For instance, in Pokémon Gold:

> Lance     : DRAGONITE, HYPER BEAM.

The Rocket grunt hit by the hyper beam is thrown into a wall; you can then talk to him:

> Urrgh... That guy's dragon POKEMON are tough...

(Pokémon Gold)

A video of the same event from Pokémon Crystal:

Comment: Fun fact: the guy Lance Hyper-Beamed shows up again in *Pokémon Masters*, as one of the NPCs that can randomly appear in the Pokémon Centre, and has developed some sort of crippling fear of Dragon-type Pokémon as a result.

Answer (score 2):

In *Pokémon: Best Wishes,* while climbing the Tower of Success, Iris gets hit with a Confuse Ray and thinks she won the race.

[image]